# What is purpose of metamodel class in JPA2.0?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, criteria-api

I was recently reading about the Criteria API in JPA2.0 specification, where they introduced the concept of having metamodel class ([see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjrij.html)). I understand how to use it, but what I do not understand is why was there a need to create this new concept just for Criteria API.

Answer (score 2):

Without metamodel, we access `name` property of `Employee` entity as below,

```
Root<Employee> employee = query.from(Employee.class);
employee.get("name");
```

using metamodel, you can shorten it to

```
Employee_.name
```

where `Employee_` is the metamodel of `Employee` entity
I think having no need to create roots for entities is the advantage of using metamodel api.

Answer (score 0):

Metamodel helps to write a typesafe code

```
CriteriaQuery<Double> c = cb.createQuery(Double.class);
Root<Account> a = c.from(Account.class);
c.select(cb.avg(a.get(Account_.balance)));
```

Here the compiler can check for errors by checking a type of balance property (for example there should be some error if a balance is a String)